# How to deserialize complicated Dictionary list JSON in C#?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have following JSON. It can be deserialize using following code.

```
List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>>> listOfOptions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>>>>(JSONdata);
```

I want to structurize `listOfOptions` following class structure.

i.e
fieldName = "prioritycode"

fieldOption 1 => Key = High, Value = 1

fieldOption 2 => Key = Normal, Value = 2

fieldOption 3 => Key = Low, Value = 3

Same way for `isescalated` and `firstresponsesent`.

```
internal class DropOptions
{
    public string fieldName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,int> fieldOptions { get; set; }

}
```

I have tried enough but not able to structure :(.

Can anybody please help me?

This is my JSON

> [{"prioritycode":{"High":{"High":1},"Normal":{"Normal":2},"Low":{"Low":3}}},{"isescalated":{"Yes":{"Yes":1},"No":{"No":0}}},{"firstresponsesent":{"Yes":{"Yes":1},"No":{"No":0}}}]

```
[
    {
        "prioritycode":
        {
            "High":
            {
                "High":1
            },
            "Normal":
            {
                "Normal":2
            },
            "Low":
            {
                "Low":3
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "isescalated":
        {
            "Yes":
            {
                "Yes":1
            },
            "No":
            {
                "No":0
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "firstresponsesent":
        {
            "Yes":
            {
                "Yes":1
            },
            "No":
            {
                "No":0
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Honestly, just use a class mapping. instead of a collection of dictionaries that holds a key to a dictionary http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @json2csharp.com Can you give me idea? I have already wasted enough time for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Json.Net** and just write something like `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);`
After deserializing json you have provided I was able to write `int normal = obj[0].prioritycode.Normal.Normal;` and `normal` variable was holding `2`. No extra classes required.

Answer (score 0):

I have done by this. It looks fine. I know it is bit difficult and having loops. But the options(prioritycode,isescalated,firstresponsesent) are dynamic. It can be more or less. Name of it can be anything else like taskStatus, productType, productCategory etc.

```
List<DropOptions> listOfOptions = new List<DropOptions>();
foreach (Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>> item in tempListOfOptions)
{
    foreach (Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> item1 in item.Values)
    {
        DropOptions objDrop = new DropOptions();
        objDrop.fieldName = item.Select(t => t.Key).FirstOrDefault();
        objDrop.fieldOptions = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (Dictionary<string, int> item2 in item1.Values)
        {
            string strKey = item2.Select(t => t.Key).FirstOrDefault();
            int strValue = item2.Select(t => t.Value).FirstOrDefault();

            objDrop.fieldOptions.Add(strKey, strValue);
        }
        listOfOptions.Add(objDrop);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This uses the Newtonsoft.Json (Json.NET) framework to Deserialize the JSON to a collection of `RootObject`. The benefit of using a strongly-typed class is that you have compile time checking, and the confidence that you're not attempting to access a property which doesn't exist or one that is misspelled.

```
public class RootObjectDeserializer
{
    List<RootObject> DeserializeRoot()
    {
        // Read string from somewhere
        string json = "[{\"prioritycode\":{\"High\":{\"High\":1},\"Normal\":{\"Normal\":2},\"Low\":{\"Low\":3}}},{\"isescalated\":{\"Yes\":{\"Yes\":1},\"No\":{\"No\":0}}},{\"firstresponsesent\":{\"Yes\":{\"Yes\":1},\"No\":{\"No\":0}}}]";
        // Deserialize to a List of RootObject
        List<RootObject> deserializedObjects = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
        // Return RootObject
        return deserializedObjects;
    }
}

//Class mappings below
public class High
{
    [JsonProperty("High")]
    public int HighProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Normal
{
    [JsonProperty("Normal")]
    public int NormalProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Low
{
    [JsonProperty("Low")]
    public int LowProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Prioritycode
{
    public High High { get; set; }
    public Normal Normal { get; set; }
    public Low Low { get; set; }
}

public class Yes
{
    [JsonProperty("Yes")]
    public int YesProperty { get; set; }
}

public class No
{
    [JsonProperty("No")]
    public int NoProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Isescalated
{
    public Yes Yes { get; set; }
    public No No { get; set; }
}

public class Yes2
{
    public int Yes { get; set; }
}

public class No2
{
    public int No { get; set; }
}

public class Firstresponsesent
{
    public Yes2 Yes { get; set; }
    public No2 No { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Prioritycode prioritycode { get; set; }
    public Isescalated isescalated { get; set; }
    public Firstresponsesent firstresponsesent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your way will work if field names are fix. You have fix the name of fields. In my case, it can be anything. We can't rely on fix fields(prioritycode, isescalated, firstresponsesent) or fix options(High, Normal, Low).

Comment: Why are you voting down valid answers because they don't meet a specific criteria in your requirements which you failed to mention? It's simple, just don't mark them as the answer.